# Installing Ubuntu on a separate D: drive with data already on it

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 with the following configuration of hard drives:

- C: 250 GB SSD. In this drive I have Windows 10 (almost all of it is used)
- D: 1 TB HDD. In this drive I have some data (about 20% of it is used), and here is where I want to install Ubuntu.

I also want to have dual boot.

How do I partition my drives before installation and what do I choose in the "Installation type" window in the setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. First you have to shrink your `D:` drive via **Partitioning manager** (Hard disk management or something like that) on Windows. Open that manager (simply press the windows button and search for it), select your `D:` partition and shrink it with as much space as you'll need on Linux. If you won't be downloading anything else on your Linux, just make sure to shrink so you have at least 60G free space. Should suffice.
2. Then start your Ubuntu installation and when it asks you for
   **"Installation type"** choose **Something else**. There you should see the free space you shrank from Windows (for example 60G of free space on your hard drive), and create & format new partitions over that free space. For starters, you can create just one 60G partition with an **Ext4** filesystem. However, I suggest you have at least 2 or 3 partitions, but only if you want to bother. If you do, check the bottom of my answer.
3. After that just continue to install. When GRUB installs (it should do it automatically, **or** it can ask you if you want it to be installed -- yes you do) it should automatically detect your Windows 10, and that way, when you boot you'll get a prompt to choose whether you want Linux or Windows.

**If you don't see Windows in GRUB, don't panic.** Boot into your Linux, open the terminal (`CTRL+ALT+T`):

`sudo os-prober` (`sudo apt install os-prober` if you don't have it)

`sudo update-grub`

And you should be ready to go.

*For a bit better partitioning:*
You need at least 2 or 3 partitions.

A root partition for your root filesystem, Ext4 (or xfs/btrfs, but I suggest Ext4), 50-70G (depending on how many packages you will install), with a mountpoint `/`.

A boot partition with size of 512M and an Ext2 filesystem for your GRUB bootloader that will boot both your Linux and Windows with a mountpoint `/boot`. (boot partition **must** be primary)

An optional third partition for your home directory where you can store all your personal data, files, and projects. Make it as big as you wish and again with an Ext4 filesystem and a mountpoint `/home`.

And an optional fourth partition - **swap**, it is useful when your system runs out of memory, as it will start using the swap so your system won't freeze. I suggest around ~**8G** of size. (just need to select "use as swap partition")

Comment: Remember that resizing a partition containg data may cause data loss. I would defragment the partition first.

Comment: If the partition is not or hasn't been a part of a RAID, I believe it should be okay, as long as the space is actually free. Windows won't allow shrinking otherwise.

Comment: @Fanatique I've read about a "swap" partition. What is it?

Comment: @milo8505 Swap partition is something like additional RAM. If some application exhausts your RAM, your machine will start using the swap partition. You can make a swap partition with size around the size of your RAM or around 8-10G max.